# How to convert a dash separated range to several entries with "X" when difference is 9 in Python

Tags: python, regex

let me try to explain what I´m trying to do:

I have a range like this: `20934-21021`

I´m trying to figure out a way to get an output like:

```
20934,20935,20936,20937,20938,20939,2094X,2095X,2096X,2097X,2098X,2099X,2100X,2101X,21020,21021
```

Currently I´m just getting the difference between both numbers and getting the output increasing the number by one each time but I would be looking for something more appropriate.

Current code:

```
import re

text = "20934-21021"
startRange = re.findall(r'(\d*)-', text)
endRange = re.findall(r'-(\d*)', text)
while int(startRange[0]) <= int(endRange[0]):
    print int(startRange[0])
    startRange[0]= int(startRange[0]) +1
```

Any ideas?

PS: values are stored in a list and using `findall` because the same line can contain several ranges.

EDIT: The aim is to simplify the output (string) from:
20934,20935,20936,20937,20938,20939,20940,20941....
To a format where any range which is 0-9 will be replaced by an X:
20934,20935,20936,20937,20938,20939,2094X,2095X...

If the difference is bigger, it would do the same for the rest of the digits, i.e:
Range= 20119-22400
Output: 20119,2012X,2013X,2014X,2015X,2016X,2017X,2018X,2019X,202XX,203XX,204XX,205XX,206XX,207XX,208XX,209XX,21XXX,220XX,221XX,222XX,223XX,22400

Comment: Is `2094X` a string? and can you explain a bit more about the logic behind the output?

Comment: `range(*map(int, text.split('-')))`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, this is not the solution. The problem description is rather different

Comment: I've presumed in my answer that `2094X` is a shorthand for `20940,20941,...,20949` - if that's incorrect please say so!

Comment: My comment ends with a question mark because I'm not sure I understand the task at hand. Can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is upvoted if no one understands what's actually being asked... >.>

Comment: @Morek...Check one of the provided answers below, and if you are not happy with them...either comment or edit your question with more details.

Comment: Yes, it´s a string. "X" means 0-9. It´s common when defining phone number ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my proposed solution:

```
>>> def range_x(s):
        start, end = s.split('-')
        result = ''
        if start[-1] == '0':
            string1 = start[:-1]+'X'
        else:
            r1 = range(int(start[-1]), 10)
            string1 = ','.join(map(lambda i:start[:-1]+str(i), r1))

        r2 = range(int(start[:-1])+1, int(end[:-1]))
        string2 = ','.join(map(lambda i: str(i) + 'X', r2))

        if end[-1] == '0':
            string3 = end[:-1]+'X'
        else:
            r3 = range(0,int(end[-1])+1)
            string3 = ','.join(map(lambda i: end[:-1]+str(i), r3))
        result = ','.join([string1, string2, string3])
        return result

>>> s = '20930-21020'
>>> range_x(s)
'2093X,2094X,2095X,2096X,2097X,2098X,2099X,2100X,2101X,2102X'
>>> s = '20934-21021'
>>> range_x(s)
'20934,20935,20936,20937,20938,20939,2094X,2095X,2096X,2097X,2098X,2099X,2100X,2101X,21020,21021'
```

Comment: I think the OP had working code that just wasn't to his liking, and it didn't have an `'X'` in each item. I think the desired output was just a shorthand way of denoting "all the numbers from 20960 to 20969," and so on.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3...That was my first understanding as well, but when I read the title twice, I saw one requirement to have range 0-9 replaced with X...in my simple understanding I guess

Comment: "How to convert a dash separated range to several entries with “X”"

and

"getting the output increasing the number by one each time but I would be looking for something more appropriate"

suggest to me that the output from this answer and answer from @Ahsanul matches what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

There are places for optimization, but I tried to make it easy and straight forward.

```
a,b  = map(int, '20934-21021'.split('-'))

output_str = ''


l = (a/10 + 1) * 10
u= (b/10) * 10

output_str += ','.join(map(str, range(a,l)))

output_str += ','

lower = a/10 + 1
upper = b/10 -1


output_str +=','.join(["{0}X".format(i) for i in range(lower, upper+1)])
output_str += ','


output_str += ','.join(map(str,range(u, b+1)))

print output_str
```

Output:

```
20934,20935,20936,20937,20938,20939,2094X,2095X,2096X,2097X,2098X,2099X,
2100X,2101X,21020,21021
```

Comment: if `a` was `20930`, it will produce numbers for the whole range `20930-20939` where it should be `2093X` .. Probably you will need to check value of `a` with an `if-else`...

Comment: Thanks, it works. This is useful when increase by 10, however if range is bigger, say 20934 - 23112 it will create all the entries just adding 10 to the previous one where it would be appropriate to add 100 or 1000. (i.e. 21XXX,22XXX,230XX,2310X,23111,23111,23112)

Answer (score -1):

The `range` function can do this for you. In Python 2 it returns a list, in Python 3 it's a generator, but these differences don't matter for the code you need.

```
text = "20934-21021"
start, end = text.split("-")
start = int(start) # needs error checks
end = int(end)     # as does this
result = ",".join(str(i) for i in range(start, end+1))
```

Comment: That's how i understood the question as well, no idea why someone would downvote this.

Comment: Without an explanation from the OP we won't know which answer is required.

Comment: Not the down voter, but that's not what OP wanted .. !

Comment: I am the down voter, and this not what  OP asked for. If I will be proved wrong, I will definitely withdraw it.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque Why not to do the opposite?

Comment: It's only reputation - I try not to worry about up- and down-votes and focus instead on helping people